# Enable Entity Framework migrations in Mono

Tags: mono, xamarin, entity-framework-6

I've started building an ASP.NET MVC3 project on Mac OS using Xamarin Studio. I now want to add new properties and models to the project but I can't for the life of me work out how to run the Nuget Package Manager console in order to run the Enable-Migrations command.

Am I asking too much? Is this possible or will I have to go back to Visual Studio on Windows?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All of the Entity Framework Migrations commands are just thin wrappers over an underlying API. To enable migrations, simply create a new class that derives from `DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext>` in your project.

For `Add-Migration` use code similar to the following.

```
var config = new MyMigrationsConfiguration();
var scaffolder = new MigrationScaffolder(config);
var migration = scaffolder.Scaffold("Migration1");

File.WriteAllText(migration.MigrationId + ".cs", migration.UserCode);

File.WriteAllText(migration.MigrationId + ".Designer.cs", migration.DesignerCode);

using (var writer = new ResXResourceWriter(migration.MigrationId + ".resx"))
{
    foreach (var resource in migration.Resources)
    {
        writer.AddResource(resource.Key, resource.Value);
    }
}
```

For `Update-Database` see [Running & Scripting Migrations from Code](http://romiller.com/2012/02/09/running-scripting-migrations-from-code/) by Rowan Miller.

## Update for EF 6.3

A command named ef6.exe has been added to the NuGet package. It contains corresponding commands for each of the PMC commands:

```
|        PMC        |        ef6.exe        |
| ----------------- | --------------------- |
| Enable-Migrations | ef6 migrations enable |
| Add-Migration     | ef6 migrations add    |
| Update-Database   | ef6 database update   |
| Get-Migrations    | ef6 migrations list   |
```

Comment: Seems like a pain in the buttocks

Comment: Still cool that you posted a solution though... not downplaying you at all... just wish it had it built in

Comment: @bricelam, where can you run this code? Should I make a separate console project? Or call a controller action?

Comment: @user2609980 I'd recommend a separate console app.

Comment: @bricelam I have used a separate console app to include the code and run the migration, but the project with the Models and database context is referenced.

Comment: To workaround the MARS limitation, you'll have to use more eager loading.

Comment: Hi @bricelam first of all thanks for responding, secondly a question regarding the eager loading: how can I implement that? The exception "MARS is not implemented" is thrown because of some setting somewhere where I have no idea where it is set. I posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069403/how-to-circumvent-mars-is-not-yet-implemented-exception.

Comment: Let me know if you have an idea or not, if not I will not try any more and just write the database scripts that map to the models myself. The code can be found [here](https://github.com/erooijak/zaaikalender) in the Zk.Migrations project, and I run on latest version of Mono. Thanks.

Comment: @bricelam Could you shine your light on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115642/what-files-am-i-missing-wile-running-migrations-from-a-console-app). I cannot get the `Update-Database` to work because a resource file is missing.

Comment: based on the [open source repo](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6) - it's a pretty big stretch to call them "thin wrappers".  There's a lot going on in the power shell scripts.