# Entity Framework & Migrations - tied to NuGet/Package Manager Console?

Tags: entity-framework, nuget

Have recently been playing round with Entity Framework to see if it's suitable for our needs. So far have just been creating POCOs to create the Database and then using Migrations to update my schema (Add-Migration/Update-Database etc)

My question is, are we absolutely tied in with the Package Manager Console in order to manage the migrations?

From what I've seen so far, the only alternatives are as follows:

-Automatic Migrations (general consensus seems to be to avoid)

-Excuting Migrations in the code (would still involve using the PMC to create the Migration files, or would involve creating them by hand)

Is there anything else I've missed? It's not a big deal if we are tied in, but would just like to know for sure.

Thanks

Comment: See my answer to [Enable Entity Framework migrations in Mono](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20382226/475031)