# Entity Framework 6 migration without NuGet?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, powershell, entity-framework-migrations

The common scenario for migrations in Entity Framework 6 is to use Package Manager Console. 
It is also possible to use migration without Package Manager Console as described:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20382226/121968 and http://romiller.com/2012/02/09/running-scripting-migrations-from-code/.

Is it possible to access migrations from Package Manager Console when Entity Framework is not deployed via NuGet?

Comment: NuGet packages are just zip files renamed. You can download the appropriate nupkg, unzip, and run the init.ps1 and/or install.ps1 manually.

Comment: @Eris I know, I am using development builds of my fork of EF6.

Comment: Can you use a toplevel NuGet.config file with a local folder? It should allow you to use your local nupkg instead of the public one giving you the best of both worlds. (reference: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuget-config-file)

Comment: The think is, that I currently do not know how to build EF6 nuget package without running all the tests.