# How to enable migrations in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: entity-framework, xamarin, visual-studio-mac

I have Visual Studio for Mac and I'm trying to learn Xamarin with Azure using the following tutorial: https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/server/

At some point, I have to enable EF migrations. The tutorial says: Go to View -> Other Windows -> Package Manager Console.

Unfortunately there is no Package Manager Console in Visual Studio for Mac... so how do you handle things like `enable-migrations`, `add-migration` or `update-database` on the Mac?

Comment: The Visual Studio `Package Manager Host` is not currently supported `macOS` using the PowerShell beta and thus trying to install/init `EntityFramework.psm1` will fail as running powershell will result in a `ConsoleHost` and thus trying to run `Import-Module` on the EntityFramework PS module will fail. The migration cmds are fairly thin wrappers over the entity framework apis and you can convert them to a C# cmd-line app fairly easily, but it is fair easier to spin up a Windows VM on the Mac... sucks, but those are the two options available today : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20382226/4984832

Comment: It is more than just supporting the Package Manager Host. There is a separate NuGet extensions addin that adds a PowerShell console. The problem is that, at least with EF 6, the PowerShell commands are Visual Studio specific. When I integrated support for the EF 6 in SharpDevelop all the PowerShell commands needed to be rewritten to work with the host IDE. EF 7 has provided cross platform commands that work on the command line using the dotnet cli. However PowerShell integration is a another problem.

Comment: The answer from @GClovs worked for me :)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

**This is currently supported on Mac.**

First you need to install dotnet-ef

`dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef`

To install a specific version of the tool, use the following command:

`dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.1.4`

Add the "dotnet-ef" tools directory on the PATH environment variable.

`export PATH="$PATH:/Users/'your user folder'/.dotnet/tools"`

Open a command line, go to the project folder, and run

`dotnet restore`

If everything is fine, you should be able to run

`dotnet ef`

After that you can run commands like:

`dotnet ef migrations add initial`

`dotnet ef database update`

**PS: Your solution should not be executing when the dotnet ef command line is trying to run!!!**

For People who are not convinced, here a demo of succeed!!!
[image: For People who are not convinced, here a demo of succeed!!!]

Comment: It should I am on Mac and this is working very well. You have to use it at the racine of your solution

Comment: Haha you troll me bro, the command line exist. You should found a way to make it work.
I am using it every day

Comment: You have to run it when your project is not running.

Comment: This worked for me on a MacBook Pro M1. Didn't need to add 'dotnet-ef' to the PATH environment variable though. Just worked!

Comment: this post deserves more upvote

Comment: This worked for me, although I had to add `--connection {CONNECTION STRING}` to the `dotnet ef database update` command.

Comment: For me the DbContext is setup in my startup project, with the connection string from my AppSettings

Answer (score 35):

To run EF on Mac just follow the following.

Open a command line, go to the project folder, and run

> dotnet restore

If everything is fine, you should be able to run

> dotnet ef

After that you can run commands like:

> dotnet ef migrations add initial
>
> dotnet ef database update

Comment: FYI... If dotnet EF doesn't you may need to install dotnet tools as it was removed in .net core 3.0

Comment: I had to run the install like this -- dotnet tool install -g dotnet-ef. There is more detail on this at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli

Comment: I needed to update to latest  dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef

Answer (score 19):

This is not currently supported with Visual Studio for Mac out of the box.

There is a NuGet extensions addin that adds a PowerShell console to Visual Studio for Mac. This is available from the Extensions Manager, and provides a NuGet Package Manager Console window, available from the View - Other Windows menu. This allows you to run the EF PowerShell commands that you can run in Visual Studio on Windows.

If you are using Entity Framework 7 (or what they are calling Entity Framework Core) then you should be able to use the commands with the [.NET Core command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet).

```
dotnet ef migrations ...
```

If you are using Entity Framework 6 then you would need to find another way to call the migrations instead of using PowerShell. Entity Framework 6 has PowerShell commands that are specific to Visual Studio. They were ported to SharpDevelop but involved re-writing them to work with that IDE.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359302/merge-tags-visual-studio-mac-and-visual-studio-for-mac?noredirect=1#comment531840_359302

Answer (score 6):

If you are using .NET Core (specifically EF Core), you can install the NuGet PowerShell Core Console in Visual Studio for Mac'.

Just follow the instructions described at:

https://lastexitcode.com/blog/2019/05/05/NuGetPowerShellCoreConsoleVisualStudioForMac8-0/

Comment: This solution Works with Visual Studio 2022 for Mac version 17.5 and EF Core 7.0.5. I fully recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

I had these errors

When i ran this command

```
dotnet ef migrations add nameOfMigration
```

The error that I got was this

```
No project was found. Change the current working directory or use the --project option.
```

Then add at the end the solution of the project that I had in the root

```
dotnet ef migrations add nameOfMigration --project project.sln
```

But it gave me another error

```
error MSB4057: The target "GetEFProjectMetadata" does not exist in the project.
```

I realized that it had to be inside the project folder and the csproj file

```
dotnet ef migrations add nameOfMigration --project Project/Project.csproj
```

And for me this was my solution

Comment: I have mac with ship M1

Answer (score 0):

Mac Users

If you have N-Layer Architecture and multiple projects, make sure you're running command on the right path (possibly under the startup project path)

I was having issues because of a wrong path

```
dotnet ef database update
```

Of course you have to install ef first

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version {VERSION_NUMBER}
```

then export path

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/firatkeler/.dotnet/tools"
```

And do not forget to install db locally if your settings are pointing to a local db. Install and try to connect it first, then apply dotnet ef database update command.